# Allowing an executable to be terminated w/ ctrl+c in a shell script w/o exiting

Tags: bash, shell

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
command_a    # starting a executable
command_b    # should be executed after after exiting A
```

A is exited via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I didn't really know how to search for this.

Comment: So do you want to run `command B` after A? But you want to deliberately terminate A before its done?

Comment: FYI, `command` is a bash keyword. Unless you literally mean you're running it, you should probably pick a different placeholder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to trap the Ctrl+C signal to do nothing but pass the control to the shell script again. 
I tried the below code and it worked for me. Replace the sleep commands by the real commands you want to execute.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Trap the Ctrl+C signal to do nothing but pass the control to the script. 
trap : INT

#Executes command A.
echo "Executing command A. Hit Ctrl+C to skip it..."
sleep 10

#Reset trap of Ctrl+C.
trap INT

#Executes command B.
echo "Executing command B. Ctrl+C exits both command and shell script."
sleep 10
```

More information can be find in the below links:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184124/on-ctrlc-kill-the-current-command-but-continue-executing-the-script

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57940/trap-int-term-exit-really-necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom handler for SIGINT.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up a signal handler that kills current process
handle_sigint() { kill "$cur_pid"; }
trap handle_sigint INT

# Start first process, and store its PID...
sleep 30 & cur_pid=$!

# Wait for it to exit or be killed...
wait

# And run the second process.
echo "running remainder"
```

Replace `sleep 30` and `echo "running remander"` with your real commands.